# Validacion de checkbox con php

Tags: php, html

¿Me podrian ayudar para saber como darle solucion a esto?...
Tengo una form sencillo, donde agrego un .csv en un textarea, me gustaria saber si puedo hacer una validacion con un checkbox con php para que cuando lo marquen, sepa que dentro del textarea van incluido un csv del cual tiene que omitir las primeras 4 lineas siempre y si no se marca es por que va a contar desde la primera linea, anexo mi codigo para darme a entender.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-MX">
    <head>
        <title>Box Lunch</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <form method="POST" action="procesa_csv.php">
            <legend align="center"><h1>Ingresa los valores de tu archivo .csv</h1></legend>
            <legend align="center"><u>*NOTA: No dejar lineas en blanco al final ni al inicio.</u></legend>
               <div class="container" align="center">
                    <p><textarea rows="20" name="areatexto" cols="100" required></textarea></p>
                    <p><input type="reset" class="btn btn-success" value="Restablecer" name="B2">
                    <br>
                    <br>
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Convertir" name="B1"></p>
               <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="line1header" value="1">Mi archivo tiene encabezado
               </p>

         </div>
        </form>    
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongamos que ya tenemos `procesa_csv.php` Lo que hice, fue hacerle un `print_r` para saber los valores que tienen tu `form`

Por ejemplo, ya dentro del archivo `procesa_csv.php` el `print_r` nos retorna esto cuando tu checkbox no está activo:

```
Array ( [areatexto] => ok [B1] => Convertir )
```

Y cuando sí está activo nos retorna esto:

```
Array ( [areatexto] => ok [B1] => Convertir [line1header] => 1 )
```

Como nuestra misión es detectar que el checkbox venga vacío, podemos trabajar en una validación como la siguiente:

```
<?php 
    $omitir_lineas = false;
    if ( isset($_POST["line1header"]) AND $_POST["line1header"] ==  1 ){
        $omitir_lineas = true;
    }
?>
```

1. Verificamos con `isset($_POST["line1header"])`  para saber si el valor de tu checkbox viene definido. Además validamos que sea igual a `1` por si acaso (este valor por defecto es el que le estás dando a tu checkbox)
2. Ocupamos la variable `$omitir_lineas` entre `true` o `false`. Como tu lógica lo menciona, si el checkbox viene activo entonces vas a omitir líneas o vas a hacer el proceso que necesitas. Si `$omitir_lineas` es falso, entonces no vas a omitir las 4 primeras líneas, sin embargo, si es true las vas a omitir.

Ya nada más queda de tu parte hacer un if adicional para validarlo como el siguiente:

```
<?php 
    $omitir_lineas = false;
    if ( isset($_POST["line1header"]) AND $_POST["line1header"] ==  1 ){
        $omitir_lineas = true;
    }

    //empiezas tu csv desde la 4ta línea
    if ( $omitir_lineas ) {

    }
    //no omites nada
    else {

    }
?>
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="procesa_csv.php">
  <legend align="center">
    <h1>Ingresa los valores de tu archivo .csv</h1>
  </legend>
  <legend align="center"><u>*NOTA: No dejar lineas en blanco al final ni al inicio.</u></legend>
  <div class="container" align="center">
    <p><textarea rows="20" name="areatexto" cols="100" required></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="reset" class="btn btn-success" value="Restablecer" name="B2">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Convertir" name="B1"></p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="line1header" value="1">Mi archivo tiene encabezado
    </p>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hermano, eres un crack! Justo lo que estaba buscando, me has ayudado un monton! :D sou nuevo en php y le estoy entendiendo, muchas gracias! :)